# First timestamp of max value in Prometheus graph

Tags: devops, prometheus, grafana, promql

I am trying to find the timestamp of the first occurrence of max value(the cursor point in below image)
[image]

I wrote query
`min(timestamp(max(jmeter_count_total{label="GET - Company Updates - ua_users_company-updates"})))`

But it's returning the max timestamp of the max value

I am not able to grab the value highlighted by cursor in below image(minimum value). Instead I am getting highest value when I use above query.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've played with this for a bit and I think this *may* work (take it with a grain of salt, due to limited testing).

TLDR - the query (using only `foo` for brevity):

```
min_over_time((timestamp(foo) and (foo == scalar(max_over_time(foo[2h]))))[1h:])
```

This portion of the query:

```
foo == scalar(max_over_time(foo[2h]))
```

returns only values where `foo` matches the max value of `foo` in the last 2h interval. For retrieving the timestamp of those cases we use the `timestamp` function and use these previous clause as a conditional:

```
timestamp(foo) and (foo == scalar(max_over_time(foo[2h])))
```

Finally we only want to get the first/lowest timestamp value over the time window, which is what the outer `min_over_time` with the nested subquery should do.

I fiddled with the online Prometheus demo using one of the metrics present there. You can check the [queries here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=caddy_http_requests_in_flight%7Bhandler%3D%22subroute%22%7D&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=caddy_http_requests_in_flight%7Bhandler%3D%22subroute%22%7D%20%3D%3D%20scalar(max_over_time(caddy_http_requests_in_flight%7Bhandler%3D%22subroute%22%7D%5B2h%5D))&g1.tab=0&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h&g2.expr=min_over_time(%0A%20%20(timestamp(caddy_http_requests_in_flight%7Bhandler%3D%22subroute%22%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20and%0A%20%20%20%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20caddy_http_requests_in_flight%7Bhandler%3D%22subroute%22%7D%20%3D%3D%20scalar(max_over_time(caddy_http_requests_in_flight%7Bhandler%3D%22subroute%22%7D%5B2h%5D))%0A%20%20%20%20)%0A%20%20)%0A%5B1h%3A%5D)&g2.tab=1&g2.stacked=0&g2.range_input=1h).